# Set full email address as username when registering through WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce under Settings/Account has an option named

> Automatically generate username from customer email

but the username it generates is not the full email address.

`my.email@example.com`

becomes `myemail` as a username.

What method would I need to hook into to override the user generation so that the 
**full email** is set as the username?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the hook `pre_user_login`

```
add_filter( 'pre_user_login' , 'wpso_same_user_email' );

function wpso_same_user_email( $user_login ) {

    if( isset($_POST['billing_email'] ) ) {
        $user_login = $_POST['billing_email'];
    }
    if( isset($_POST['email'] ) ) {
        $user_login = $_POST['email'];
    }
    return $user_login;
}
```

Comment: From the code I assume this will use the email as the user login when the user actually logs in. This will not integrate cleanly with woocommerce as it sends out an email stating the user name so I really want the username to be the email address, not just fake it upon login. I also have some other code relying on the username, hence my desire to actually set the username to the email address.

Comment: I have tested this code, and it populates the user_login field in database. So no faking while login. It simply filters the username before a user is created so I think emails will be fine too, but I haven't tested the email.

Comment: Thanks, I will test this.

Comment: So i've added this into the functions.php but using the default WooCommerce signup, this does not seem to change the username. I assume woocommerce uses different functions to create the actual user.

Comment: I tested this with default woocommerce sign up form "My Accounts" page

Comment: Make sure your input field is named 'email'

Comment: thanks for the pointer. turns out WooCommerce uses a different field when signing up through the checkout pathway. added a check for 'billing_email' and now it works.

Answer (score 8):

You can use something like this in your functions.php. The `woocommerce_new_customer_username` filter could be used to change the generated username. If you just return the customer email as the username, it will be used instead of the generated one (in your case the name before @).

```php
function my_new_customer_username( $username, $email, $new_user_args, $suffix ) {
    return $email;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_customer_username', 'my_new_customer_username', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Do you know if this covers new registrations AND usernames generated from checkout? Currently I've had separate functions to match the same desired output.

Comment: Well, it seems both ways are using wc_create_new_customer function and this function is using wc_create_new_customer_username which is filtered by the approach above. I have tested new registrations / checkout registrations and both profiles have usernames same as email addresses, so after this quick testing, I would yes, it covers.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Will review my code and see how it goes!

Comment: This is the better answer as it's specific to WooCommerce whereas Varun's answer will be filtered anytime `wp_insert_user` is called

Comment: Works great, but watch out as the WordPress username sanitization process strips (at least) '+' signs from emails (used a lot in the gmail world). Means if you then try to programmatically find a user from a the email based username, you won't find it as the username is missing the '+'... Just took me 3 hours to figure out. To fix you can edit the way WordPress sanitizes usernames (follow this: https://www.craig-edmonds.com/solved-allow-wordpress-accept-plus-sign-usernames/)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for reviving an old thread, but it seems this is the best option (goes in your child functions.php or custom plugin)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_customer_data', function( $data ) {
    $data['user_login'] = $data['user_email'];
    return $data;
    } );
```

here are 2 source references: [1](https://kb.checkoutwc.com/article/62-how-to-force-woocommerce-to-use-email-address-as-username-when-registering-a-new-account) and [2](https://gist.github.com/clifgriffin/697d99bc221739e67065cc953cbb70f7)